# I need to separate a string using trim()

Tags: php

How can I separate the string "JavaScript and PHP are so much fun!" using trim() in PHP?

Each has to be on a separate line.

They all work except "and" returns "d" and "are" returns "e". Can anyone help?

```
<?php
$str12 = "JavaScript and PHP are so much fun!";
echo rtrim($str12,"and PHP are so much fun!");
echo "<br>";
echo trim($str12,"JavaScript PHP are so much fun!");
echo "<br>";
echo trim($str12,"JavaScript and are so much fun!");
echo "<br>";
echo trim($str12,"JavaScript and PHP so much fun!");
echo "<br>";
echo trim($str12,"JavaScript and PHP are much fun!");
echo "<br>";
echo trim($str12,"JavaScript and PHP are so fun!");
echo "<br>";
echo ltrim($str12,"JavaScript and PHP are so much");
?>
```

Comment: No idea what you want to do here and what your question is

Comment: what does _Each has to be on a separate line_ mean?

Comment: what does *separate a string using trim()* mean?

Comment: You mean on each word? Just do `echo implode( "\n", explode(" ", $str12) );`.

Comment: Replace `\n` with `<br>` and I think you've got it, at least as far as I can tell @Darren

Comment: @TinyGiant I thought of doing that but forgot [this](http://www.tehplayground.com/#YXqRXEsg4) prints it out formatted haha.

Comment: [`trim()` in manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). The 2nd parameter is `string $character_mask`. If you pass `"JavaScript and PHP are so much fun!"` as second parameter, it is equivalent to trimming any of `[ !HJPSacdefhimnoprstuv]` so won't leave much :) Probably you just wanted something like this: [`echo trim($str12) . "<br>";`](https://eval.in/524259)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be You want to do this.. check this codes.... This may help you..

```
<?php
$str = "java and php are so much fun";
$pieces = explode(" ", $str);
foreach($pieces as $separate){
$separate;
echo str_replace($separate,'', $str);echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: None of the suggestions work. It basically is a question about trim. For some reason it is trimming the "an" and displaying "d" only, and trimming out the "ar" and displaying "e". It should display like this:

Comment: JavaScript (then on a new line) and (then on a new line) PHP etc.